# DB2 connection from excel macro

Tags: vba, db2

I want to connect to DB2 from excel macro...This is my code, but it not working, Its giving error as 'Run-time Error'...Can anyone help me...

```
Option Explicit

Dim DBCONSRT, QRYSTR As String

Dim DBCON, DBRS  As Object

Private Sub query()
    DBCONSRT = "Driver=jdbc:db2://my_host;Database=PRTHD;hostname=NZ1;port=5355;protocol=TCPIP; uid=my_user;pwd=my_pass"
    'CHANGE THE BELOW QUERY STRING ACCORDING TO YOUR NEED
    QRYSTR = "select * from PRTHD.STRSK_OH_EOO"
    Set DBCON = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    DBCON.ConnectionString = DBCONSRT
    DBCON.Open
    'BELOW CODE USED TO GET THE DATABASE CONECTION AND EXECUTE THE QUERY CHANGE ACCORDIGN TO YOUR NEED
    Set DBRS = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    With DBRS
        .Source = QRYSTR
        Set .ActiveConnection = DBCON
        .Open
    End With    
End Sub
```

---

**Edit:** I have changed my code to the following, but I'm still getting an error.  The Error is "cant create Object"..Can ayone help me..

```
Dim DBCONSRT, QRYSTR As String

Dim DBCON  As Object

Sub query()

    DBCONSRT = "Provider=MSDASQL.1;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=user;Data Source=NZ1;DSN=NZ1;UID=user;SDSN=;HST=ibslnpb1.sysplex.homedepot.com;PRT=4101;Initial Catalog=PRTHD;"

    DBCON = CreateObject("OLEDB.Connection")
    DBCON.ConnectionString = DBCONSRT
    DBCON.Open()
End Sub
```

Comment: I could be wrong, but I don't think that you can use JDBC with Excel.  I think you're wanting ODBC.

Comment: Did you mean `CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JDBC functionality I am pretty sure is not supported through vba and I think you need to use ODBC connectors to connect to  DB2 if you are trying to integrate it into excel.

```
Private Sub query()
  DBCONSRT = "Provider=MSDASQL.1;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=user;Data Source=NZ1;DSN=NZ1;UID=user;SDSN=;HST=ibslnpb1.sysplex.homedepot.com;PRT=4101;In‌​itial Catalog=PRTHD;"
  Using connection = New OleDbConnection(DBCONSRT )
      connection.Open()
      Dim cmd = connection.CreateCommand()
      cmd.CommandText = QRYSTR //This is where your sql statement should go, or the variable that is equal to the query.
      Using dr = cmd.ExecuteReader()
          //Process your query results here 
      End Using
  End Using
End Sub
```

Comment: You would need to change the ADODB object to OLEDB objects.

Comment: I changed the code like this..But its not working.Error is "Cannot create object"...Wat to do...
Sub query()

        DBCONSRT = "Provider=MSDASQL.1;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=user;Data Source=NZ1;DSN=NZ1;UID=user;SDSN=;HST=ibslnpb1.sysplex.homedepot.com;PRT=4101;Initial Catalog=PRTHD;"

        DBCON = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
        DBCON.ConnectionString = DBCONSRT
        DBCON.Open()
    End Sub

Comment: See the edit I did above and try something similar to that. Also, your connection string looks a little unusual for DB2 as you have two different user IDs in there and no password.

Answer (score 0):

Start with changing

```
DBCON = CreateObject("OLEDB.Connection")
```

to

```
Set DBCON = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
```

If you still get an error, [double-check your connection string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms675326%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).